# Issue with RSpec and FactoryGirl (avoid code repetition)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I'm actually writing tests using RSpec. The following code is in `spec/requests/tasks_spec.rb`.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Tasks" do

  env_headers = {'HTTP_ACCEPT' => Mime::JSON, "devise.mapping" => Devise.mappings[:user] }

  describe "GET /tasks" do
    context "with valid credentials" do
      user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)
      authorization_header =  ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic.encode_credentials(user.authentication_token, nil)
      env_headers['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = authorization_header

      it "should succeed" do
        get '/tasks', nil, env_headers
        response.status.should eq(200)
      end
    end

    context "with invalid credentials" do
      authorization_header = ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic.encode_credentials("123456", nil)
      env_headers['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = authorization_header

      it "should fail" do
        get '/tasks', nil, env_headers
        response.status.should eq(401)
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Since I'm not only going to just have tests for GET (but PUT, DELETE, etc), I would like to avoid code repetition concerning user instantiation. If I actually move `user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)` outside a context I'll not be able to access to `user` variable because of a scope issue.

- I would like to know if there's a best practice in RSpec to actually
  make this user reusable for each context.
- And more, but optional if I can make it usable only for specific
  contexts such as (in my case) : `context "with valid credentials"`
  (since I don't need an user for my `with invalid credentials`
  context).

UPDATE :

By using let I was still getting a scope issue, and it was due to a stupid mistake. I was asking for a user outside my it block. The following code is ok :

```
describe "Tasks" do

  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.build(:user) }

  describe "GET /tasks" do
    context "with valid credentials" do

      it "should succeed" do
        authorization_header =  ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic.encode_credentials(user.authentication_token, nil)
        env_headers['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = authorization_header

        get '/tasks', nil, env_headers
        response.status.should eq(200)
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the following once outside your context:

```
describe "Tasks" do

  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.build(:user) }

  # your tests
```

`let` is lazy loaded, which means that it will be evaluated each time only if called in your spec when doing something like `user.a_method`, or simply calling `user`.

FYI you can specify RSpec to evaluate directly the `let` by adding a "!"

```
let!(:foo) { 'foo' } # will be evaluated right away
```

Comment: Hello Pierre-Louis,

Yep I know, that's the behaviour I was expecting since I proceed this way with my controllers spec. But the problem here, in my requests specs, is that I was asking for an user outside an `it` block. And of course in this case a user isn't defined, what a stupid mistake ! ;).

Thanks anyway for your help ! I'll accept your answer.